# Commutative diagrams with five nodes

Tags: tikz-cd

I am unable to get the arrow from E pointed to B. Please suggest a solution.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
& A \arrow[dashed]{r}{\psi} \arrow[hook]{d}
& B \\
& C \arrow{r}{\phi}
& D \arrow[hook]{r}{\mu}
& E \arrow[hook]{u}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Could you describe more clearly how you would like the A, B, C, D and E to be placed and connected?

Comment: Yes. There are two rows in the diagram. The first row should look like : A ---------------> B  (with a long right arrow). The bottom row looks like C --> D --> E . Connecting these two rows, we have arrow from A to C and E to B  (There is no arrow upwards from D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MWE that could do the job.

I think these tikz-cd -pictures as latex tables/arrays:

- Each column is separated by '&'
- Each row is separated with '\\'.
- To make longer arrows, use two 'r's instead of one. This will make the arrow go "through" one column (just like 'multicolumn' in array enviroment) 
  [image]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}


\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A  \arrow[dashed]{rr}{\psi} \arrow[hook]{d}  &&  B \\
C  \arrow{r}{\phi} &  D \arrow[hook]{r}{\mu} &   E \arrow{u}
\end{tikzcd}
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: excelllent. Thank you very much. The explanation given helps me a lot in the future.

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider marking this as 'accepted answer'. Happy tikzcd'ing!